# Python pandas resampling

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Timestamp    S_time1   S_time2   End_Time_1   End_time_2   Sign_1   Sign_2
0    2413044       0        0           0            0          x        x
1    2422476       0        0           0            0          x        x
2    2431908       0        0           0            0          x        x
3    2441341       0        0           0            0          x        x
4    2541232   2526631   2528631     2520631      2530631      10       80
5    2560273   2544946   2546496     2546496      2548496      40       80
6    2577224   2564010   2566010     2566010      2568010     null    null
7    2592905   2580959   2582959     2582959      2584959     null    null
```

The table goes on and on like that. The first column is a timestamp which is in milliseconds. `S_time1` and `End_time_1` are the duration where a particular sign (number) appear. For example, if we take the 5th row, `S_time1` is 2526631, `End_time_1` is 2520631, and the corresponding `sign_1` is 10, which means from 2526631 to 2520631 the sign 10 will be displayed. And the same thing goes to `S_time2` and `End_time_2`. The corresponding values in `sign_2` will appear in the duration from `S_time2` to `End_time_2`.

I want to resample the index column (`Timestamp`) in 100-millisecond bin time and check in which bin times the signs belong. For instance, between each start time and end time there is 2000 milliseconds difference. So the corresponding sign number will appear repeatedly in around 20 consecutive bin times because each bin time is 100 millisecond. So I need to have two columns only: one with the bin times and the second with the signs. Looks like the following table: (I am just making up the bin time just for example)

```
Bin_time   signs
...100        0
...200        0
...300        10
...400        10
...500        10
...600        10
```

The sign 10 will be for the duration of the corresponding S_time1 to End_time_1. Then the next sign which is 80 continues for the duration of S_time2 to End_time_2. I am not sure if this can be done in pandas or not. But I really need help either in pandas or other methods.

Thanks for your help and suggestion in advance.

Comment: I think you will be better off treating the timestamps in all columns as integers. The reason for my thought is that these appear to be epoch times counting down to some event, and converting them to timestamps will only lengthen your code. In addition, you are only interested in relative values, not absolute. Timestamps are also harder to work with, and have a larger overhead. My personal experience also indicates that `pd.resample()` might not work for you. So, simply use the histogram function, or write your own function to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
print df
  Timestamp  S_time1  S_time2  End_Time_1  End_time_2 Sign_1 Sign_2
0    2413044        0        0           0           0      x      x
1    2422476        0        0           0           0      x      x
2    2431908        0        0           0           0      x      x
3    2441341        0        0           0           0      x      x
4    2541232  2526631  2528631     2520631     2530631     10     80
5    2560273  2544946  2546496     2546496     2548496     40     80
6    2577224  2564010  2566010     2566010     2568010   null   null
7    2592905  2580959  2582959     2582959     2584959   null   null
```

2 approaches:

```
In [231]: %timeit s(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop

In [232]: %timeit m(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 690 ms per loop
```

```
def m(df):
    #resample column Timestamp by 100ms, convert bak to integers 
    df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype('timedelta64[ms]')
    df['i'] = 1
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
    df1 = df[[]].resample('100ms', how='first').reset_index()
    df1['Timestamp'] = (df1['Timestamp'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')).astype(int)
    #felper column i for merging
    df1['i'] = 1
    #print df1

    out = df1.merge(df,on='i', how='left')
    out1 = out[['Timestamp', 'Sign_1']][(out.Timestamp >= out.S_time1) & (out.Timestamp <= out.End_Time_1)]
    out2 = out[['Timestamp', 'Sign_2']][(out.Timestamp >= out.S_time2) & (out.Timestamp <= out.End_time_2)]

    out1 = out1.rename(columns={'Sign_1':'Bin_time'})
    out2 = out2.rename(columns={'Sign_2':'Bin_time'})

    df = pd.concat([out1, out2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset='Timestamp')
    df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
    df = df.reindex(df1.index).reset_index()
    #print df.head(10)
```

```
def s(df):
    #resample column Timestamp by 100ms, convert bak to integers 
    df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].astype('timedelta64[ms]')
    df = df.set_index('Timestamp')
    out = df[[]].resample('100ms', how='first')
    out = out.reset_index()
    out['Timestamp'] = (out['Timestamp'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')).astype(int)
    #print out.head(10)

    #search start end 
    def search(x):
        mask1 = (df.S_time1<=x['Timestamp']) & (df.End_Time_1>=x['Timestamp'])
        #if at least one True return first value of series
        if mask1.any():
                return df.loc[mask1].Sign_1[0]
        #check second start and end time
        else:
                mask2 = (df.S_time2<=x['Timestamp']) & (df.End_time_2>=x['Timestamp'])
                if mask2.any():
                    #if at least one True return first value
                    return df.loc[mask2].Sign_2[0]
                else:
                    #if all False return NaN
                    return np.nan

    out['Bin_time'] = out.apply(search, axis=1)
    #print out.head(10)
```

Comment: You have used the S_time1, end_time_1, S_time2 and end_time_2 as bin time. But I want to use the first column ('Timestamp') as resampling column (bin time). And check from where to where the start time and end times lay in the bin time and fill the signs accordingly. If that makes sense.