# Python pandas column merging

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to the following but very large:

**`col1        col2
  0           0
  0           0
  1           2
  3           4
  5           6
  0           0`**

In my actual table the numbers are timestamps which are in order, not in one number difference, but one is larger than the previous as shown in this dataframe. I want the two columns to be merged into a single column according the order of numbers. I want the resulting column to be like the following:

**`column
   0
   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   0`**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the structure of the DataFrame you have or the DataFrame you want is. Could you check to see that it's formatted the way you expected?

Comment: I have a dataframe with two columns as shown above. And the entries are timestamps which are in order as shown. Now what I want is, I want to create a column which which is a merging of the two columns according their order. if that makes sense

Comment: That does make sense, give me a minute and I'll come up with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here you go, using your contrived DF as an example:

```
df.column = df.col1.append(df.col2).sort_values()
```

Upon rereading your question you may be looking for [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

```
df.column = pd.concat([df.col1,df.col2],axis=0)
```

Comment: I have tried your code but I am getting the following error message: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: Fascinating, can you change it to sort () and see if that helps?

Comment: Oh for some reason sort_values() is working now. but how do I drop all the 0 entries in the resulting column?

Comment: You could try drop_duplicates (), does that do the job?

Comment: Thanks It does do the job. I had another question in another thread which no one seem to give me a proper answer with some codes. here is the link to it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898674/python-pandas-resampling). I really need it badly for my research. So if you have time you can try it for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am about to turn in for the night. I took a look at the question and it looks doable but I need a little more energy to make the logic look right. Also, I would appreciate any advice on this if you use IPython: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/303501/keeping-an-ipython-project-maintainable-and-reliable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96197/discussion-between-same-and-josh-rumbut).

Comment: I am actually new to IPython. I have started using it recently. So I am afraid If I can help you a lot on that. But regarding my question I can explain to you If something is unclear