# Create Time Ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I want to apply a similar approach of this question [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)
 but with time ranges.

I have a dataset about restaurant orders that contains time and order type. There is a time interval for breakfast, lunch and dinner.

Time intervals:

> breakfast: (8:00:00 - 12:00:00) lunch: (12:00:01-16:00:00) dinner:
>   (16:00:01-20:00:00)

Dataset sample:

```
order_type  time
0   Lunch   13:24:30
1   Dinner  18:28:43
2   Dinner  17:17:44
3   Lunch   15:46:28
4   Lunch   12:33:48
5   Lunch   15:26:11
6   Lunch   13:04:13
7   Lunch   12:13:31
8   Breakfast   08:20:16
9   Breakfast   08:10:08
10  Dinner  18:08:27
11  Breakfast   10:42:15
12  Dinner  19:09:17
13  Dinner  18:28:43
14  Breakfast   09:21:07
```

My `time` column was originally type `object` and I converted it to `timedelta64[ns]`.

I want to create three time ranges, one for each `order_type`. Then use them to validate the accuracy of my dataset.

When I have the three ranges I can run something like the below `for loop`:

```
for order in dirtyData['order_type']:
    for time in dirtyData['time']:
        if order=='Breakfast' and time not in BreakfastRange:
            *do something*
```

I referred to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576786/how-to-use-dataframe-between-time-function). To apply `between_time` but I kept getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.cut`:

```
# threshold for time range
bins = pd.to_timedelta(['8:00:00', '12:00:00', '16:00:00', '20:00:00'])

# cut:
df['order_type_gt'] = pd.cut(df['time'],
                             bins, 
                             labels=['Breakfast','Lunch', 'Dinner'], 
                             include_lowest=True)
```

output:

```
   order_type     time order_type_gt
0       Lunch 13:24:30         Lunch
1      Dinner 18:28:43        Dinner
2      Dinner 17:17:44        Dinner
3       Lunch 15:46:28         Lunch
4       Lunch 12:33:48         Lunch
5       Lunch 15:26:11         Lunch
6       Lunch 13:04:13         Lunch
7       Lunch 12:13:31         Lunch
8   Breakfast 08:20:16     Breakfast
```

Comment: Nice ha , 7 sec

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your solution. What is `ranges` and what is `bins`?

Answer (score 2):

We can using `pd.cut`, then you just need to match the output with your original `order_type`

```
pd.cut(df.time,pd.to_timedelta(['00:00:00','12:00:00','16:00:00','23:59:59']),labels=['B','L','D'])
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. I am amazed of how simple the code is.